# Exception when passing complex model to view

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Contact()
{
    var url = @"http://mimijumi-dev.myshopify.com/blogs/news.atom";
    string result;
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(result);

    XmlNodeReader xreader = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc);
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RssFeedModel));
    RssFeedModel rssFeedItem = (RssFeedModel)deserializer.Deserialize(xreader);
    xreader.Close();
    xreader.Dispose();

    return View(rssFeedItem);
}
```

The `deserializer` populates these models:

```
[XmlRoot("feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class RssFeedModel
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public List<Link> link { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("entry")]
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("link")]
public class Link
{
    [XmlAttribute("rel")]
    public string rel { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("entry")]
public class Entry
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("published")]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
}
```

The view is pretty simple, as it just tries to display the count of `entry` elements:

```
@Model.entry.Count
```

This throws the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'web.app.Models.RssFeedModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[web.app.Models.RssFeedModel]'.
>       Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(Object value)

The RssFeedModel has elements that are lists, but it itself is not a list (or shouldn't be, based on the model classes). What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Show the model declaration in the view - i.e `@model ???` (it appears you have `@model List<RssFeedModel>` when it should be `@model RssFeedModel`)

Comment: The error shown gives you the problem.   This occurs _before_ it gets to `@Model.entry.Count` and is most likely because of the wrong @model declaration on the view (as per @StephenMuecke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count can only be applied on Collection or List, here you are passing only single RSS Feed Item to the view. Pass the List of RSSFeedItems.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Contact()
{
    ......

    List<RssFeedModel> feeds = new List<RSsFeedModel>();

    XmlNodeReader xreader = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc);
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RssFeedModel));

    feeds.Add((RssFeedModel)deserializer.Deserialize(xreader));

    xreader.Close();
    xreader.Dispose();

    return View(feeds);
}
```

Comment: `@Model.entry.Count` if getting the count of the property `entry` which is a collection in the model - `public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }`